# php Object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function, ternary-operator

I'm creating a search-function for my PHP-based file manager.  I'm getting this error: 'Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string' on the following line:

```
if ($data->input_ext)
{
    $data_ext = ($begun ? ($data->input_logic ? ' OR ' : ' AND ') :
    function ()
    {
        $begun = true;
        return "";
    }) . 'ext = "' . $data->input_ext . '"';
    $data_string.= $data_ext;
}
```

That's part of what builds the SQL query.  $begun_files simply determines whether or not to put 'OR' or 'AND' at the beginning based on whether or not the user input a name or anything that comes before this to match.  I have a feeling that I'm not allowed to include anonymous functions in ternary expressions but what should I do instead?

Thanks!

Comment: `function() { $begun_files = true; return ""; }).'size '` --- what would you expect to get as a result of this expression execution? (for a second - you're concatenating an anonymous function and a string)

Comment: Is there a reason why everything must be on a single line?

Comment: @Jack: it's more performant

Comment: @zerkms Ah right, that explains it :)

Comment: Sorry, that's just the way I write.  I've made some changes to the code but I still have the same problem.  I'll repost it, formatted.

Comment: I just want this: if $begun is true, then write 'OR' or 'AND', and if it's false, set $begun true.

Comment: @zerkms suggest a php minfier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use anonymous functions for inline flow control; just use a regular `if` statement and don't shun writing things on multiple lines:

```
if ($data->input_size) {
  if ($begun_files) {
      $str .= $data->input_logic ? ' OR ' : ' AND ';
      $begun_files = true;
  }
  $str .= sprintf('size %s "%f"',
      $data->input_size_op ? '<=' : '>=',
      $data->input_size * pow(1024,$data->input_size_unit)
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Never used sprintf() before but it looks really useful.  I think when I reposted the code I posted the wrong (but similar line) but I ended up going with something like what you wrote so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the previous answer I ended up going with this:

```
if ($data->input_ext) { 
    if ($begun) { $logic = $data->input_logic ? ' OR ' : ' AND '; } else { $logic = ""; $begun = true; }        
    $data_ext = $logic.'ext = "'.$data->input_ext.'"'; $data_string .= $data_ext;
}

if ($data->input_size) { 
    if ($begun) { $logic = $data->input_logic ? ' OR ' : ' AND '; } else { $logic = ""; $begun = true; }
    $data_size = $logic.'size '.($data->input_size_op ? '<=' : '>=').' '.($data->input_size * pow(1024,$data->input_size_unit)); $data_string .= $data_size;
}
```

Thanks!